# Tkinter Application Name/Menu

Tags: python, tkinter, py2app

How do I change this menu?

[image: python app info]

Used py2app to convert it. PS: The app is called py.app.

**Edit to further clarify:**

I would like to edit the names of the menu items under the "py" cascade and what methods they trigger. For example: About py, Services, Hide py etc.

Comment: I'm working on it pig! Gimme a day or two.

Comment: From what i can see you can do it in cocoa but not python. You would need to create a MainMenu.nib file and edit that. I will keep on finding.

Comment: Ah ok thanks very much! I'll see what I can find too. Is the .nib file editable in a text editor or is it compiled?

Comment: I think it's editable but it looks like it is mabey html.

Comment: Hey pig I'm not going to keep on posting on this old question until I get the answer so go to [this](http://pythonqanda.weebly.com) website to contact me via email.

Comment: Hello? Has it worked?

Answer (score -1):

To edit/add items to the Application Menu go [here](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/menus.html) and read the section on Mac OS X. It tells you exactly how to do it and lots of other useful things.